# Get path to user home directory from WinPython

Tags: python, windows, path

Usually, the commands `pathlib.Path.home()` or `os.environ['HOME']` allow to get the user home directory in Python, see for example [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-find-the-real-user-home-directory-using-Python).

However, when I launch these commands from the WinPython Command Prompt, it returns the settings directory in the WinPython folder instead, e.g.:

```
>>> pathlib.Path.home()
WindowsPath('C:/Users/myName/WPy64-3741/settings')
```

What can I do to get the actual user home dir?

Comment: A user account in Windows has both a home directory ("%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%") and a profile directory ("%USERPROFILE%"). Often they're the same directory, but not necessarily. In some contexts the home directory may not be set or may be set to "%SystemRoot%\System32", which is the case for a secondary logon (e.g. "runas.exe").

Comment: Neither the home directory nor the profile directory is correct for finding special folders such as "Desktop" or "Documents". The default paths for special folders are relative to the profile directory, but you can't rely on the default paths. Also, if you're following platform conventions, settings go in a subdirectory of the local application data directory ("%LOCALAPPDATA%") or roaming application data directory ("%APPDATA%"), not in the home directory or profile directory.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use the `HOMEDRIVE` and `HOMEPATH` variables instead, like so:

```
os.environ['HOMEDRIVE'] + os.environ['HOMEPATH']
```

Answer (score 0):

This code help me get the operating System directory:

```
os.environ['HOMEDRIVE']
```

OutPut: C:

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).